# Transpose XYZ coordinate to surface of sphere C#

Tags: c#, transpose, cartesian-coordinates

I have a program that I am working on that generates a random X, Y, and Z coordinate. The bounds of this is a cube and in my case, a 500x500x500 pixel cube (you are only viewing it in 2D). My question is, how can I take these points, and transpose them onto a sphere contained in that cube? In this case it would be a sphere with a radius of 250 pixels.

I have already read many articles and can't seem to find a solution that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: You need to multiply the points with a spherical matrice

Comment: When you said transpose, I'm not entirely sure what kind of output that you are expecting, but you could start with getting the centre of the cube and make that as the centre of your sphere. The radius would be 250px. Use any library to generate vertices out of it, if that what you're after.